# Positioning wrapfigures in the middle of a page

Tags: floats, positioning, margins, wrapfigure

The [overleaf tutorial for wrapfigures](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Wrapping_text_around_figures) says

> Take care while using adding wrapfigures very near the top or bottom of a page, as this can often cause unwanted effects that are hard or near-impossible to solve

I also realized that this causes problems, but I don't really know how to avoid putting a wrapfigure at the top or bottom of a page. The only idea that I have is putting it in the middle of a paragraph of text, but that would destroy the text flow.
So, is there any way to tell a wrapfigure where it should be located on a page, or even better, that it should put itself anywhere that is not the top or bottom of a page?

Comment: To avoid these unwanted effects, you should look at the `insbox` set of plain TeX macros package. It defines useful  `\InsertBoxL, \InsertBoxR` and `InsertBoxC` commands.

Comment: The {L} and {R} options will wait until the next paragraph if there isn't enough room left on the page..  It does not go to the top of the page, but the top of the first new paragraph on that page.

Comment: There are several ways to move a wrapped figure to the top of a page, but all of them require manually breaking a paragraph (except \newpage or \needspace).

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, but as far as I can tell there is no way to add a caption, just like I would to a figure.

Comment: It is possible: put your figure in a `\parbox` of a convenient size, load `caption`, if you don't already` do it, and use `\captionof{figure}{...}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I already tried {L} and {R}, while they basically do what I asked for I would prefer not to use them since this puts the figure into the next chapter, which starts only a couple of pages later.

Comment: So you have something that barely fits on one page, and it keeps being pushed back. So manually break a paragraph.  Using the number of lines argument to compensate for extra vertical space is just as ad hoc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I don't think I get it. I tried `\\*` or `\\` but that doesn't change the location of my figure. I already have a bunch of seperate paragraphs between where I specified the wrapfigure up to where it actually appears. Also not exactly sure what the number of linese argument is. As you may have noticed I am very new to LaTeX and I couldn't find anything relevant when I searched for that term either

Answer (score 1):

Some things are easier to show than explain.  This is what I mean by "break a paragraph".  You can insert wrapfigure in the middle of a paragraph, but it has to be at the end of a line.  So write the text without wrapfigure to locate the correct word to start after.  If you are still revising, use a figure [p] until the final draft.

BTW, I've never heard of a problem from having wrapfig too close to the top of a page.

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
 
\begin{document}
       
\lipsum[1-5]

\sloppy
Suspendisse vel felis. Ut lorem lorem, interdum eu, tincidunt sit amet,
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=0.8\textheight]{example-image}
  \caption{test}
\end{wrapfigure}
laoreet vitae, arcu. Aenean faucibus pede eu ante. Praesent enim elit, rutrum
at, molestie non, nonummy vel, nisl. Ut lectus eros, malesuada sit amet, fermentum
eu, sodales cursus, magna. Donec eu purus. Quisque vehicula, urna sed
ultricies auctor, pede lorem egestas dui, et convallis elit erat sed nulla. Donec
luctus. Curabitur et nunc. Aliquam dolor odio, commodo pretium, ultricies
non, pharetra in, velit. Integer arcu est, nonummy in, fermentum faucibus,
egestas vel, odio.

\lipsum[7-9]
\fussy
  
\end{document}
```